# Android SDK Development - Inject Views into host app

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, android-library

I'm working on an Android library with a need to show some UI elements in or over the hosting app. The web version of this library simply adds a banner message to the top of the screen, but I'm unsure about doing the same. I've found it fairly easy to accomplish this by removing the app's view tree from `android.R.id.content`, adding it to a layout I inflated, and then adding the new view tree back to `android.R.id.content`. It works great in my demo app, but I'm worried about there being cases I can't think of where this would cause issues for devs using this library. This UI is related to screen sharing and I want it easy and obvious that the screen is being shared as well as how to stop sharing.

1. Is it safe to wrap my UI around the host app's?
2. Should I try using the Bubble API instead? (Seems great except that users can opt-out)

Comment: Why would you do it that way?  If you want them to display a UI element, create a View and/or Fragment that they can add to their layout where it makes sense for their app.

Comment: @GabeSechan Because one of our major selling points is providing fully-functional UI to our customers.

Comment: A fragment or view they can add to their own layout is providing fully functional UI.  All they need to do is drop it into their layout and they're done.  No library I've ever seen on Android has tried to do it by dropping their UI into its own container, its definitely not a great pattern.  Have you tested what happens if they use fragments and fragment transactions?  Especially around activity recreation?  Sounds likely to be fragile.